# Transferring an int from view to controller in C# using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to transfer an integer from my view to my controller.  I am using Ajax to do this and below is my html code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Yes" id="return"
onclick="returnBook(@item.BookID);"/>
```

My ajax:

```
function returnBook(id) {
console.log(id);
var bookID = id;
var url= '/AuthenticatedUser/ReturnBook';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: bookID,
    success: function (results) {
    }
});
```

}

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReturnBook(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In my controller, when I use a string, the method is invoked but the id remains set to null.  However, if I use a 'int id', the method is not invoked at all and I get a 500 error.  Any idea how I can pass the id from view to controller?

Comment: Are you using some additional library or framework? Because in general, the string `@item.BookId` will _not_ magically get replaced by the value of some field. In general, you would have to get it from your form, for example `<input type='hidden' id='bookId' value='...' />` and then `returnBook(document.getElementById("bookId").value)` (or `$('#bookId')` if you use jQuery as your tags imply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send an object instead:

```
data: { id:bookID },
```

Now you can use the key `id` of this object at your controller to get the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

MVC will automatically try to match data values passed from your web page to the arguments declared in your controller.

So when you are sending a variable `bookID` MVC will try to match that to a variable named `bookID` in your controller's argument list.  As that argument doesn't exist the associated value is disregarded.

To fix your problem you either want to change your controller declaration to -

```
public ActionResult ReturnBook(string bookId)
```

or change your data declaration to either

```
data: id,
```

or (as Jai suggests) -

```
data: { id:bookID },
```