# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in c# Razor pages) when doing AJAX call from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, razor-pages

I have a razor page model. In this model there is a get-Method.

```
public IActionResult OnGetDuration([FromBody]int id)
    {
        Subject subject = _service.GetSubjectById(id);
        int duration = subject.LessonsPerWeek;
        return new JsonResult('a');
    }
```

I call this method with Ajax in JavaScript:

```
function getHours(i, studentId) {
var selection = document.getElementById('select_' + i);
var id = parseInt(selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value);
var json = JSON.stringify(id);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/Subjects/Choose?handler=Duration",
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: alert('error calling my ajax request')
    });
}
```

This leads to an error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType,
JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterConte
xt context, Encoding encoding)
at

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterConte
xt context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext
bindingContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext,
IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata
metadata, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageBinderFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.
<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.BindArgumentsCoreAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.
g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope
scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object&
state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.
g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint,
Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This error seems to be caused when receiving the json on server side.

An ID for example 81 is given to the ajax call. But I am receiving the parameter id = 0 on C#.

If I send the id as string the parameter received on C# is null.

This id leads to a Nullreference Excption in the GET C# method.

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: The console output (Error) is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: I cant find the request body in the developer tools of Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I cannot see a request body there but a request header.

Comment: This is the request header:

Comment: :authority: localhost:5001
:method: GET
:path: /Subjects/Choose?handler=Duration&81&_=1605273709748
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://localhost:5001/Subjects/Choose?id=10
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin

Comment: user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36 Edg/86.0.622.68
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: GET doesn't have `data` to send in the request ... that `data: json` does nothing, i.e. you're not sending an id at all ... nevermind, jquery appends the data to the URL ... so, your url `Subjects/Choose?handler=Duration&81&_=1605273709748` ... the `81` is the data ... how will C# know to look for that?

Comment: see if `var json = JSON.stringify({id});` helps

Comment: This code does not help. The same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for me it is not clear what you are trying to do.
Your method says [FromBody], however I can't see the body in your ajax request.

By chance is the Duration the value You want to receive on the ID parameter? 
           url: "/Subjects/Choose?handler=**Duration**".

If so, then You are trying to  pass the value as query string.
Change your method to

```
([FromQuery]int id)
```

and your url call to

```
url: "/Subjects/Choose?id=Duration"
```

---

Or another approache, change your route to

```
@page "*here the current route*/{id}"
```

and your method to

```
([FromRoute]int id)
```

Comment: No ,I want to send the id and the id is the parameter of the C# method  public IActionResult OnGetDuration([FromBody]int id)

Comment: yes, but how do you want to send it, as body or query parameter? Your ajax call doesn't send any Id and doesn't  include any body. Net core side is not able to bind any data coming from your request with the id parameter.

Comment: url: "/Subjects/Choose?handler=Duration"

Comment: No necessarily, you're url could be OK, but as it is, it doesnt match the method  signature. Because your method is expecting the id from body, but you are passing it as query string. "handler=duration". Change your method to [FromQuery] and your url call to "/Subjects/Choose?id=Duration"

Comment: I want to send the id to the C#-method using AJAX. But I don't know how to match it to the method signature.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341668/transferring-an-int-from-view-to-controller-in-c-sharp-using-ajax helped me to solve my problem.